# Texture image erased for no reason wondering if i can somehow get it back

Tags: texturing

[image: The texture that has gone missing. Note how the thumbnail has colours yet the image loaded doesn't and is instead blank]

Ok, so I'm making a model and I make the textures and all that, I switch over to "modelling" to create a new object, I switch back and the textures are just gone note how the thumbnail has colours yet the image loaded doesn't and is instead blank. I cant access them in materials either they also seem to blank. I don't think anyways. I think they may have also been erased

[image: Materials screenshot]

I'm kind of leaving my blender to run overnight so I don't lose it. so i would highly appreciate help, thanks!

Comment: I can't tell from the images.. are you in _Solid Preview Mode_ by any chance? If so, press Z in the 3D viewport and select either _Material Preview_ or _Rendered_ from the pie menu. To make sure you don't lose a material that is not being used, hit the little "shield icon" (false user) next to the material name.

Comment: It's not the textures on the actual model that have been erased its the actual texture itself. it's gone fully blank after switching to modelling. I have not closed blender without saving or anything like that at all